# Xamarin Android como reiniciar tiempo de reposo de pantalla ScreenOffTimeout

Tags: android, xamarin.android

en una aplicación cambio el tiempo de reposo de pantalla así:

```
    Settings.System.PutString(this.ContentResolver, Settings.System.ScreenOffTimeout, TIEMPO);
```

Todo funciona bien, pero si en un layout quiero que el reposo sea de 15 segundos (tiempo=15000 milisegundos) y luego durante una tiempo lo cambio a 30 minutos (1800000) para que no se bloquee la pantalla durante una barra de progreso, al volver a ponerlo a 15 segundos el contador no se reinicia asi que se bloquea casi de inmediato puesto que estubo contando durante la barra de progreso.

Alguien sabe como reiniciar el contador de ScreenOffTimeout?